# How to get the natural height of a box in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I need to do some calculation in which the actural height of a `tcolorbox` has to be introduced(Please see the following code for my purpose). I wonder if there is such a macro(\macro in my code as an example, not `\tcbtextheight`) to store the value of the actual box height.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    lefthand width=3em,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=0pt,sidebyside,enhanced,
    colback=green!60,
    bicolor,colbacklower=gray,
    collower=white,
    underlay={
        \path[fill=green!60]
        (segmentation.south) -- ++(0.5\macro,0.5\macro)--(segmentation.north);},
    ]
    Upper
    \tcblower
    \quad This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

From above code, I want to get the following effect
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this examples, the cleanest way is to extract the height dimension from `segmentation`. Therefore,

```
\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\macro{segmentation}
```

will do the trick.

The full code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    lefthand width=3em,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=0pt,sidebyside,enhanced,
    colback=green!60,
    bicolor,colbacklower=gray,
    collower=white,
    underlay={
        \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\macro{segmentation}
        \path[fill=green!60]
        (segmentation.south) -- ++(\dimexpr0.5\dimexpr\macro,\dimexpr0.5\dimexpr\macro)--(segmentation.north);},
    ]
    Upper
    \tcblower
    \quad This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this will not look good, if the box becomes too large. The solution of Ignasi gives no rectangular angle, but is more stable for different heights.

Comment: Many thanks for your simple and perfect soluntion. Yet, I change "-- ++(\dimexpr0.5\dimexpr\macro,\dimexpr0.5\dimexpr\macro)" by " --([xshift=0.5\dimexpr\macro]segmentation.center)", the typeset gives no rectangle angle which I think it should be (as the height and width are equal). Could you tell me the cause?

Comment: And If the upper/lower parts are not sidebyside, how to get the natual height of a box?

Comment: For your changed code, you missed a `\dimexpr` before `0.5`.

Comment: The node `frame` can alternatively used for the height of the whole box (even without lower part), i.e. `\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\macro{frame}`

Comment: Could you tell me why \dimexpr must be used before 0.5 and what the unit is for \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\macro{frame,segmentation etc},only a value? or a length?

Comment: With `\dimexpr`, the following text is computed as dimensional expression and the result is a length (or better, length register, as far as I know). `\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\macro` sets `\macro` to be a text with value and unit, e.g. `100pt`. Therefore, we need `\dimexpr\macro` to create a length register which gets scaled with `0.5`

Answer (score 7):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    lefthand width=3em,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=0pt,sidebyside,enhanced,
    colback=green!60,
    bicolor,colbacklower=gray,
    collower=white,
    underlay={
        \path[fill=green!60]
        (segmentation.south) -- ([xshift=5mm]segmentation.center)--(segmentation.north)--cycle;},
    ]
    Upper
    \tcblower
    \quad This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

It's possible to draw an arrow proportional to box height with `calc` tikzlibrary help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    lefthand width=3em,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=0pt,sidebyside,enhanced,
    colback=green!60,
    bicolor,
    colbacklower=gray,
    collower=white,
    underlay={
        \path[fill=green!60] 
        let \p1=($(segmentation.north)-(segmentation.south)$), 
            \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        (segmentation.south) -- 
        ([xshift=\n2/2]segmentation.center) --
        (segmentation.north)
        {[rounded corners]-|(frame.west)|-(segmentation.south)}--
        cycle;},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
    Upper
    \tcblower
    \quad \lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
    Upper
    \tcblower
    \quad This is one sentence
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ignasi, your solution does well In my example where the content of the lower part contains only one line of text.  Howerver, the angle formed at the segmentation.center becomes larger if multilines of text are typeset in the lower part. This is because of the fixed value of xshift=5mm. So I think 0.5 height of the box should solve the problem which I don't know how to get it. Anyone could give me a clue to it(how to get the natual height of a tcolorbox)?

Comment: @lyl Please, see my update.