# Use of \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode with a dimension in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Based on the ingenious answer in my question about dimensions in `tcolorbox`, [Exact dimensions in tcolorbox-4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395879/exact-dimensions-in-tcolorbox-4/396016?noredirect=1#comment985369_396016), I want to obtain an improvement, important in my opinion for the readability, which makes the vertical bars as long as the height of the node of the box... I recall the `.tex` file given in the answer:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below right, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=.8cm, align=center,
   font=\bfseries] at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style 2 args={
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable, 
        colback=white, colframe=white, 
        sharp corners, 
        boxrule = 0mm, 
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,
%       varwidth boxed title,
        tikznode boxed title={minimum width=\textwidth/4-15mm-4.5mm},
        attach boxed title to top right={%
            xshift=.5mm,yshift=- \tcboxedtitleheight+.5mm},
        boxed title style={%
            enhanced,
            sharp corners, 
            colframe=#1!75!black, 
            left=1mm, right=1mm,
            boxrule=.5mm},
        colbacktitle=#1!5!white, 
        coltitle=black,
        extrude right by=-15mm,
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([shift={(15mm-.5\pgflinewidth,-15mm+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east)|-([shift={(-\textwidth/4+15mm,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-15mm+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west)|-([shift={(\textwidth/4,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west);        },
        underlay unbroken and last={%
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0)--(0,0);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(0,15mm);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)--+(0,15mm);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0)--(\textwidth,0);
        },
    },
    mytitle/.style 2 args={
        code={%
            \ifstrempty{#1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize}}}
            {\tcbset{
                title={#1},
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize},
                underlay unbroken and last={
                    \draw [#2!75!black,line width=.5mm](frame.south east)--++(180:\tcboxedtitlewidth-\pgflinewidth);
                }}}
        },
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop},
    mytitle={#2}{blue},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def},
    mytitle={#2}{green},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
A non-titled definition
\vspace{2.2cm}
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
A titled proposition
\vspace{2cm}
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[height=2cm,label=Exlab]{A}
A titled definition
\end{definition}
\ref{Exlab}
\end{document}
```

and its compilation with xelatex:

[image]

Now I want to make the vertical bars, of length 15mm, to have the height of the boxnode.
I found in the doc of the tcolorbox, in the section **12.9 Extracting Node Dimensions**, the command `\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode`, which seems to do the job, but I can't use it. After some googlin', I found this question [How to get the natural height of a box in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391492/how-to-get-the-natural-height-of-a-box-in-tcolorbox), where the answers talk about it's use, but I can't apply it on my question. So my question is : How can I replace the dimension 15mm in the boxes by the height of the boxnode (called myboxnode in the program) ?

I tried something like this fragment in the code, but the compilation gives nothing... It runs indefinitely !

```
    \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\myheight{\myboxnode{#2}{#1}},
    underlay unbroken and first={%
        \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
        \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([shift={(15mm-.5\pgflinewidth,-\dimexpr\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east)|-([shift={(-\textwidth/4+15mm,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east);
        \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-\dimexpr\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west)|-([shift={(\textwidth/4,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west);        },
    underlay unbroken and last={%
        \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0)--(0,0);
        \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(0,\dimexpr\myheight);
        \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)--+(0,\dimexpr\myheight);
        \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0)--(\textwidth,0);
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode` needs the name of a node, not the whole definition of the node itself. For example, if you do  `\node (A) at (1,1) {Foobar};` or `\node [name=A] at (1,1) {Foobar};`, then `A` is the name of the node, and

```
\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\myheight{A}
```

will give the height of the node.

Hence you need to modify your `\myboxnode` macro to for example

```
\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below right, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=.8cm, align=center,
   font=\bfseries] (tmpbox) at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}
```

Note the addition of `(tmpbox)`. You can then add

```
\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\myheight{tmpbox}
```

on the line immediately after `\myboxnode{#2}{#1}`, and use `\myheight` later.

Complete code (note that the `\dimexpr` you had are not needed):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below right, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=.8cm, align=center,
   font=\bfseries] (tmpbox) at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style 2 args={
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable, 
        colback=white, colframe=white, 
        sharp corners, 
        boxrule = 0mm, 
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,
%       varwidth boxed title,
        tikznode boxed title={minimum width=\textwidth/4-15mm-4.5mm},
        attach boxed title to top right={%
            xshift=.5mm,yshift=- \tcboxedtitleheight+.5mm},
        boxed title style={%
            enhanced,
            sharp corners, 
            colframe=#1!75!black, 
            left=1mm, right=1mm,
            boxrule=.5mm},
        colbacktitle=#1!5!white, 
        coltitle=black,
        extrude right by=-15mm,
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\myheight{tmpbox}
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]
              ([shift={(15mm-.5\pgflinewidth, -\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east) |- 
              ([shift={(-\textwidth/4+15mm,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]
              ([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west) |-
              ([shift={(\textwidth/4,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west);

           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0) -- (0,0);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west) -- +(0,\myheight);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east) -- +(0,\myheight);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
         },
    },
    mytitle/.style 2 args={
        code={%
            \ifstrempty{#1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize}}}
            {\tcbset{
                title={#1},
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize},
                underlay unbroken and last={
                    \draw [#2!75!black,line width=.5mm](frame.south east)--++(180:\tcboxedtitlewidth-\pgflinewidth);
                }}}
        },
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop},
    mytitle={#2}{blue},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def},
    mytitle={#2}{green},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
A non-titled definition
\vspace{2.2cm}
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
A titled proposition
\vspace{2cm}
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[height=2cm,label=Exlab]{A}
A titled definition
\end{definition}
\ref{Exlab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just saw your solution, very ingenious. The creation of the temporary box tmpbox was the key of that. I have now a really beautiful macro for my theorems, and such. Thank you for making Texyfying so beautiful

Comment: Sorry but there's a problem for the "long-titles boxes". For example, if I use the command `mystyle={blue}{Proposition},`, the title "Proposition" writes on a single line,  out the boxnode. What's the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna An educated guess: the first word in a paragraphs cannot be hyphenated (broken across lines), and "Proposition" is longer than the `text width` of 0.8cm that you have set for `\myboxnode`. If you want to enable hyphenation you can write `\hspace{0pt}Proposition` instead of `Proposition`, but you might want to increase the `text width`.

Comment: Thank you for your educated comment. This remark was for a "Proposition-definition" environment...in arabic, what I use, the translation of these two  words is lesser-width than .8 cm... but not the two words.. But after testing in "real conditions", i.e. in arabic environment, it's hyphenated, so all is good. Many thanks.

Comment: I am interested to an improvment of your so beautiful macro. Can I obtain a boxnode of width depending in the width of the title !? More precisely, can I use some command like 

`\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below right, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=\widthof{#1}, align=center,
   font=\bfseries] (tmpbox) at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}
` 

by putting `text width=\widthof{#1}` ? .. I tried it but I have an error

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Remove `text width`altogether, then the node will be the width of the content. Otherwise, try `text width=width("#1")`.

Comment: Thank you for your amability. I tried `text width=width("#1")` and it gives the suitable thing but the box is not centered around the words 'Def' or 'Prop'. How can I make it centered ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Try `text width=width("\textbf{#1}")`.

Comment: I tried it but I have the error message `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna That worked fine here, so no idea why you'd get that error. I suggest asking a new question about that problem.

Comment: Excuse me for recalling the problem. If I use the command `text width=width("#1")` the title box will be far from the box node.. How can I make it at a fixed distance from the boxnode, say 1mm, for all the width nodes, titled like Def, Prop, Theorem.. and so?.. In this case, one must play with the command `attach boxed title to top right={xshift=...` and the length of xshift must depend on the width of node. I tried to do this, but fail !

Comment: Good morning. would you see this new question, please

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408584/use-of-tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode-with-a-dimension-in-tcolorbox-2