# Use of \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode with a dimension in tcolorbox-2

Tags: tcolorbox

Based on the very ingenious answer in my question about dimensions in `tcolorbox`,

[Use of \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode with a dimension in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397033/use-of-tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode-with-a-dimension-in-tcolorbox/399697?noredirect=1#comment1018710_399697)

I want to make a refinement which will do my macro more beautiful. 
I explain: in my original question, I wanted to use the height of my title node, and not for its width because the width is fixed... on the original question to .8cm.

Now I want to make the width of the box variable too, based on the length of the title. I can do this, thanks to a comment on the answer of my post, by using the command `text width=width("#1")`, and I have about that two questions:

1. This command gives the suitable thing but the box is not centered around the title. How can I make it centered ?
2. Now I want to put the title on a fixed distance, say 1 mm, from the title box, so use the width of the title box, like the use of its height. We can do this with a third argument, to use a command like:

   ```
   attach boxed title to top right={%
           xshift=#3,yshift=- \tcboxedtitleheight+.5mm},`
   ```

   where `#3` will be something like `\mywidth+2mm`, obtained by a similar command of the height... 
   `\tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode\mywidth{tmpbox}`

Now I know that I can't use commands like `\tcbset{mystyle/.style 2 args`, for more than two arguments, and that in this case, my  idea is that we must use commands like `\DeclareTColorBox`, not `\newtcolorbox`, but I haven't succeed to implement it. Any helpful answer please ? Many thanks.

I give the .tex file used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below left, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=width("#1"), align=center,
   font=\bfseries] (tmpbox) at ([xshift=13.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style 2 args={
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable, 
        colback=white, colframe=white, 
        sharp corners, 
        boxrule = 0mm, 
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,
%       varwidth boxed title,
        tikznode boxed title={minimum width=\textwidth/4-15mm-4.5mm},
        attach boxed title to top right={%
            xshift=.5mm,yshift=- \tcboxedtitleheight+.5mm},
        boxed title style={%
            enhanced,
            sharp corners, 
            colframe=#1!75!black, 
            left=1mm, right=1mm,
            boxrule=.5mm},
        colbacktitle=#1!5!white, 
        coltitle=black,
        extrude right by=-15mm,
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\myheight{tmpbox}
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]
              ([shift={(15mm-.5\pgflinewidth, -\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east) |- 
              ([shift={(-\textwidth/4+15mm,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]
              ([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west) |-
              ([shift={(\textwidth/4,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west);

           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0) -- (0,0);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west) -- +(0,\myheight);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east) -- +(0,\myheight);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
         },
    },
    mytitle/.style 2 args={
        code={%
            \ifstrempty{#1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize}}}
            {\tcbset{
                title={#1},
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize},
                underlay unbroken and last={
                    \draw [#2!75!black,line width=.5mm](frame.south east)--++(180:\tcboxedtitlewidth-\pgflinewidth);
                }}}
        },
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop},
    mytitle={#2}{blue},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def},
    mytitle={#2}{green},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
A non-titled definition
\vspace{2.2cm}
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
A titled proposition
\vspace{2cm}
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[height=2cm,label=Exlab]{A}
A titled definition
\end{definition}
\ref{Exlab}
\end{document}
```

and its compilation, using xelatex:

[image]

Comment: At the moment I don't see how the pgfkey setting `.style 2 args` is connected to `\DeclareTColorbox` however

Comment: Sorry the command was true... note the command `\myboxnode{#2}{#1};` in `style 2 args` !

Comment: The talk about `\DeclareTColorbox` is my idea ... I correct the question abouit this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following some comments, here is more or less a complete rewrite. It also takes into account possible page breaks in boxes (seeing as you do have `breakable` in the style), by drawing the top corners in `underlay unbroken and first`, and the bottom corners in `underlay unbroken and last`.

One of the changes I've made is to manually add the title using a `\node` in the `underlay unbroken and first`. That change makes the `extrude right by` unnecessary, as far as I can understand, which in turn makes all the 15mm adjustments here and there unnecessary.

Doing this also makes the positioning of the title easier, as it can be placed relative to the `tmpbox` and `frame` nodes.

I've also removed the `mytitle` style, instead adding a fourth argument to `mystyle` that is for the title. The stuff necessary for the parshape is moved to a `set parshape/.code`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % for the let-syntax    

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}

\newlength\LineW
\setlength\LineW{0.5mm}
\tikzset{
  frameline/.style={
    draw=#1!75!black,line width=\LineW
  }
}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[
   fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
   below left, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=width("#1")*1.2,
   align=center,
   font=\bfseries
   ] (tmpbox) at 
     ([xshift=-1mm-0.5\LineW,yshift=-1mm-0.5\LineW]frame.north east)
   {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style n args={4}{
        enhanced jigsaw,
        breakable, 
        colback=white,
        opacityframe=0,
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm,
        left=2mm, right=2mm,
        % drawing corners on top and title
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\HHH{tmpbox}
            % \global\let so it's available outside the underlay unbroken and first
            \global\let\myheight\HHH
            % 
            \ifstrempty{#4}{ % if no title
                % draw top right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([shift={(0, -\myheight)}]frame.north east) |- 
                      ([shift={(-\textwidth/4,0)}]frame.north east);
            }{ % if title
                % add node with title
                \node [anchor=north east,
                       inner xsep=2mm,
                       fill=#1!5!white,
                       frameline={#1}
                      ]
                     (titlenode)
                     at
                     ([xshift=-#3,yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]frame.north -| tmpbox.west)
                     {#4};

                % draw top right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]titlenode.north east) -|
                      ([yshift=-\myheight]frame.north east);

                % calculate distance from corner of frame to opposite corner of title
                % save in \mywidth
                \path let \p1=(frame.north east), \p2=(titlenode.north west), \n1={\x1-\x2} in
                    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\WWW}{\n1}\global\let\mywidth\WWW}
                ;
            }
            % draw top left frame
            \draw [frameline={#1}]
                  ([shift={(0,-\myheight)}]frame.north west) |-
                  ([shift={(\textwidth/4,0)}]frame.north west);

        },
        % if box breaks across pages, draw corners on last part
        underlay unbroken and last={%
            \ifstrempty{#4}{ % if no title
                % draw bottom right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([shift={(0, \myheight)}]frame.south east) |- 
                      ([shift={(-\textwidth/4,0)}]frame.south east);
            }{
                % draw bottom right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([xshift=-\mywidth]frame.south east) -|
                      ([yshift=\myheight]frame.south east);
            }
            % draw bottom left frame
            \draw [frameline={#1}]
                  ([yshift=\myheight]frame.south west) |- 
                  ([xshift=\textwidth/4]frame.south west);
        },
        set parshape/.code={%
            % 0.666em is twice the inner sep
            % 6mm is 2mm from left, 2mm from right, 1mm right of box, 1mm left of box
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\parwidth}{\hsize-(width("#2")*1.2+0.666em+6mm)}
            \ifstrempty{##1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \hsize}
                    }
            }
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \hsize},
             }}
        },
       set parshape={#4}
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop}{1mm}{#2},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def}{1mm}{#2},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[height=2cm,label=Exlab]{A}
A titled definition
\end{definition}
\ref{Exlab}

\begin{definition}{A}
 A long titled definition
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

## Original answer

I think this might be at least a partial answer.

You can have more than 2 arguments to a style by using

```
mystyle/.style n args={n}{<style definition>}
```

so below I used

```
mystyle/.style n args={3}{...
```

To get the proper amount of shift (at least roughly), I added the following to `mystyle`:

```
        titleshift/.code 2 args={%
         % * width("##1")*1.2 is same as used in\myboxnode
         % * but ##1 refers to the first argument passed to the titleshift key
         % * double ## required because #1 would refer to the first argument
         %   passed to mystyle
         % * ##2 is the second argument passed to titleshift, which is the third
         %   argument passed to mystyle 
         % * +0.5pt is the line width of \myboxnode
         % * -11mm looks OK, but I'm not entirely sure why that value is required
         %   It's the "extrude right by"-value minus 4mm-ish
         \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\titlexshift}{width("##1")*1.2+##2+0.5pt-11mm}
        },
        % use the titleshift key, which will set the \titlexshift macro
        titleshift={#2}{#3},
```

The first part defines a `titleshift` key that takes two arguments. The `.code` handler evaluates the code inside it, which here defines a length macro using `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\titlexshift}{width("##1")*1.2+##2+0.5pt-11mm}`. (See the comments above for explanation.) When the key is used with `titleshift={#2}{#3}`, it takes the second and third argument passed to `mystyle` as inputs.

And because `mystyle` now has three mandatory arguments, you have to use `mystyle={blue}{Prop}{1mm}` instead of `mystyle={blue}{Prop}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
    below left, minimum height=2em, 
   text width=width("#1")*1.2, align=center,
   font=\bfseries] (tmpbox) at ([xshift=13.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style n args={3}{
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable, 
        colback=white, colframe=white, 
        sharp corners, 
        boxrule = 0mm, 
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm, left=2mm, right=2mm,
%       varwidth boxed title,
        tikznode boxed title={minimum width=\textwidth/4-15mm-4.5mm},
        titleshift/.code 2 args={%
         % * width("##1")*1.2 is same as used in\myboxnode
         % * but ##1 refers to the first argument passed to the titleshift key
         % * double ## required because #1 would refer to the first argument
         %   passed to mystyle
         % * ##2 is the second argument passed to titleshift, which is the third
         %   argument passed to mystyle 
         % * +0.5pt is the line width of \myboxnode
         % * -11mm looks OK, but I'm not entirely sure why that value is required
         %   It's the "extrude right by"-value minus 4mm-ish
         \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\titlexshift}{width("##1")*1.2+##2+0.5pt-11mm}
        },
        % use the titleshift key, which will set the \titlexshift macro
        titleshift={#2}{#3},
        attach boxed title to top right={%
            xshift=-\titlexshift,yshift=- \tcboxedtitleheight+.5mm},
        boxed title style={%
            enhanced,
            sharp corners, 
            colframe=#1!75!black, 
            left=1mm, right=1mm,
            boxrule=.5mm},
        colbacktitle=#1!5!white, 
        coltitle=black,
        extrude right by=-15mm,
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\myheight{tmpbox}
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]
              ([shift={(15mm-.5\pgflinewidth, -\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east) |- 
              ([shift={(-\textwidth/4+15mm,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north east);
            \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm]
              ([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-\myheight+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west) |-
              ([shift={(\textwidth/4,+.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west);

           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)(\textwidth/4,0) -- (0,0);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([xshift=.25mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south west) -- +(0,\myheight);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([xshift=14.75mm,yshift=.25mm]frame.south east) -- +(0,\myheight);
           \draw [#1!75!black,line width=.5mm] ([yshift=.25mm]frame.south east)(3*\textwidth/4,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
         },
    },
    mytitle/.style 2 args={
        code={%
            \ifstrempty{#1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize}}}
            {\tcbset{
                title={#1},
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \dimexpr \hsize-14mm\relax
                    0pt \hsize},
                underlay unbroken and last={
                    \draw [#2!75!black,line width=.5mm](frame.south east)--++(180:\tcboxedtitlewidth-\pgflinewidth);
                }}}
        },
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop}{1mm},
    mytitle={#2}{blue},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def}{1mm},
    mytitle={#2}{green},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
A non-titled definition
\vspace{2.2cm}
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
A titled proposition
\vspace{2cm}
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[height=2cm,label=Exlab]{A}
A titled definition
\end{definition}
\ref{Exlab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71445/discussion-on-answer-by-torbjorn-t-use-of-tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode-with-a-dim).

Comment: would you see this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426423/use-of-tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode-for-parshape-in-tcolorbox, related and based on your ingenious answer. Many thanks