# Use of \tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode for \parshape with the tcolorbox package

Tags: tcolorbox

I use this ingenious answer to my question, [Use of \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode with a dimension in tcolorbox-2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408584/use-of-tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode-with-a-dimension-in-tcolorbox-2),  to produce environments with tcolorbox, and I want to implement a variant of it. More precisely, in my old post,the box of the title of the environments is put as "vertical" by putting a maximum for a width of the `boxnode` by using the command `text width=width("#1")*1.2`. Now, my aim is to put the title on one line, so I avoid this command. After, one  must arrange the parshape after the box, with a stuff taking in account the width of the `boxtitle`. I tried to use command like the command using `\tcbsetmacrotoneightofnode`, so I tried the following one:

```
       \tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode\BBB{tmpbox}
       \global\let\myboxwidth\BBB
```

and the command `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\parwidth}{\hsize-\myboxwidth}` instead of `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\parwidth}{\hsize-(width("#2")+0.666em+10mm)}`, but I have an error. It appears that the use of the length `\myboxwidth` is refused inside `set parshape/.code={..` but accepted inside `underlay unbroken and last={..` for example !

So how must I define the `\myboxwidth` command to use it for parshape, to indent the text by a fixed length after the box, even with variable width?

I give the file used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % for the let-syntax    

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}

\newlength\LineW
\setlength\LineW{0.5mm}
\tikzset{
  frameline/.style={
    draw=#1!75!black,line width=\LineW
  }
}

\newcommand{\myboxnode}[2]{%
\node[
   fill=#2!5!white, draw=#2!75!black, line width=.5pt, 
   below left, minimum height=2em, 
 %  text width=width("#1")*1.2,
   align=center,
   font=\bfseries
   ] (tmpbox) at 
     ([xshift=-1mm-0.5\LineW,yshift=-1mm-0.5\LineW]frame.north east)
   {#1 \thetcbcounter}}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style n args={4}{
        enhanced jigsaw,
        breakable, 
        colback=white,
        opacityframe=0,
        top=2mm, bottom=2mm,
        left=2mm, right=2mm,
        % drawing corners on top and title
        underlay unbroken and first={%
            \myboxnode{#2}{#1};
            \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\HHH{tmpbox}
            % \global\let so it's available outside the underlay unbroken and first
            \global\let\myheight\HHH
            \tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode\BBB{tmpbox}
            \global\let\myboxwidth\BBB
            % 
            \ifstrempty{#4}{ % if no title
                % draw top right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([shift={(0, -\myheight)}]frame.north east) |- 
                      ([shift={(-\textwidth/4,0)}]frame.north east);
            }{ % if title
                % add node with title
                \node [anchor=north east,
                       inner xsep=2mm,
                       fill=#1!5!white,
                       frameline={#1}
                      ]
                     (titlenode)
                     at
                     ([xshift=-#3,yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]frame.north -| tmpbox.west)
                     {#4};

                % draw top right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]titlenode.north east) -|
                      ([yshift=-\myheight]frame.north east);

                % calculate distance from corner of frame to opposite corner of title
                % save in \mywidth
                \path let \p1=(frame.north east), \p2=(titlenode.north west), \n1={\x1-\x2} in
                    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\WWW}{\n1}\global\let\mywidth\WWW}
                ;
            }
            % draw top left frame
            \draw [frameline={#1}]
                  ([shift={(0,-\myheight)}]frame.north west) |-
                  ([shift={(\textwidth/4,0)}]frame.north west);

        },
        % if box breaks across pages, draw corners on last part
        underlay unbroken and last={%
            \ifstrempty{#4}{ % if no title
                % draw bottom right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([shift={(0, \myheight)}]frame.south east) |- 
                      ([shift={(-\textwidth/4,0)}]frame.south east);
            }{
                % draw bottom right frame
                \draw [frameline={#1}]
                      ([xshift=-\mywidth]frame.south east) -|
                      ([yshift=\myheight]frame.south east);
            }
            % draw bottom left frame
            \draw [frameline={#1}]
                  ([yshift=\myheight]frame.south west) |- 
                  ([xshift=\textwidth/4]frame.south west);
        },
        set parshape/.code={%
            % 0.666em is twice the inner sep
            % 6mm is 2mm from left, 2mm from right, 1mm right of box, 1mm left of box
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\parwidth}{\hsize-(width("#2")+0.666em+10mm)}
            \ifstrempty{##1}
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\parshape 4
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \hsize}
                    }
            }
            {\tcbset{
                before upper={\vspace*{\baselineskip}\parshape 3
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \parwidth
                    0pt \hsize},
             }}
        },
       set parshape={#4}
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proposition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={blue}{Prop}{1mm}{#2},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{definition}[2][]{%
    mystyle={green}{Def}{1mm}{#2},
    #1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{definition}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{A long title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

and its compilation:
[image]